# How can i make a calculated column out of other columns (with triggers)?

Tags: mysql

I am trying a project of making a food nutrition database for budgeting.

These are some of my columns in my table "products": fat, carbs, dietary fiber, protein (and), kilojoules, calories. (its pr 100g)

My goal is to have fat, carbs, dietary fiber, and protein determine and update kilojoules and calories. I believe I have to be using **triggers** if I have to do this in MySQL and PHPMyAdmin? How can I do this?

As of now, I have been making values based on inserted values from a PHP-Html form I made.

I used these approximate calculations:

```
$kilojoulespr100g = round(($carbs+$protein)*17+$fat*37+$dietary_fibre*8, 0);

$caloriespr100g = round($kilojoulespr100g*0.239005736, 0);
```

I am expecting that I can be able to not worry about the columns "kilojoules" and "calories" being updated accordingly to amounts of fat, carbs, dietary fiber, and protein so that it always will be corrected if the amount of fat, carbs, protein or dietary fibres is changed.

Comment: MySQL supports native calculated columns (it is called Generated Columns), but using a VIEW might be better for this case.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the columns are named as carbs, protein, fat, dietary_fiber, kilojoulespr100g and caloriespr100g, you can use the following trigger-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trigger_name` BEFORE INSERT ON `test_nutrition` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET new.kilojoulespr100g = round( (new.carbs + new.protein) * 17 + (new.fat * 37) + new.dietary_fiber * 7 );
    SET new.caloriespr100g   = round( new.kilojoulespr100g * 0.239005736 );
END
```

You can omit the second parameter in round function as it is optional and takes 0 as default value.